# Red hat hibernate button missing

Tags: rhel, hibernate

I have two computers (z800 hp workstations). They have same version of Red Hat operating system ("5.4 tikanga").

One of them has hibernate button on shutdown menu. Also, there is a disk option in `/sys/power/state`. The other PC doesn't have the option to hibernate.

How can enable this option?

Comment: Do you have a swap partition? Also, please follow this answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17010/how-to-hibernate-a-rhel6-machine

Comment: Where did you find these ancient unsupported systems?

Comment: @jsbillings yes they are, I don't have permission to download and upgrade anything for them.